# C++: Unable to resolve identifier cout, Netbeans, Ubuntu

Tags: c++, netbeans, ubuntu-11.04, cout

I am using C++ on Netbeans 7.1 on Ubuntu 11.04.  For some reason, the following code results in the error message "Unable to resolve identifier cout".

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello,world!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Any help resolving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can get decent code formatting just by putting four spaces at the start of each line (or using `<code>` tags) - you don't need to miss about with escaping `#` characters and using `&lt;`.

Comment: Linking as C instead of C++, perhaps?

Comment: Possibly, @Fred, but I'd expect to see the error far sooner. The given error message seems to be a compiler one rather than a linker one and, if it was gcc rather than g++, it would barf on the include.

Comment: Same issue as this? http://forums.netbeans.org/ntopic28340.html

Answer (score 4):

The solution for your problem is at least strange ;) 
Once iostream header is added, one has to reparse code. Click right on a project, go to code assistance and click to reparse project. Worked for me.
I was using netbeans for mac.

Answer (score 1):

check whether iostream is really getting included;
i have tried your code on my machine using eclipse cdt it worked fine.so, please check the 
includes.

Answer (score 1):

What sort of file is this in? Is it a .h file, or .hpp file? I had this same issue. Netbeans can be ridiculous sometimes with C++. For me, I changed `#include <iostream>` to `#include<iostream.h>`

Answer (score 1):

This may seem too simple, but...

In my NetBeans installation, when I go to create a new project, specify C/C++,  it brings up a dialog box prompting for "Project Name:", location, folder, makefile name, and then...
 a check box for "Create Main File", an edit box with "main" filled in, and to the right of that is a drop down list that reads "C". If you hit Finish, this will create "main.c" (C, but NOT a C++ file). Instead, in the drop down list, select "C++". Then the IDE creates main.cpp, which will be compiled with g++ and will find those includes and functions.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between std::cout and cout.  You don't currently have std::cout defined in your file.  std::cout is a c standard out.  In C++ we only need cout to work with iostream.

If you must use a standard c out then do the following:

Add this to the top under iostream

```
#include <iostream> //Input output stream in C++
#include <cstdlib> //Stands for c standard library
using namespace std;
```

Your code will now work because:
This change defines std::cout and std::cin among other things. (standard in, standard out respectively.)

However, I'd recommend this alternative if you don't need standard in outs:
Replace std::cout with cout, because cout is defined in iostream in C++.  Your program would have worked without the std:: portion of your cin cout commands because you originally included iostream.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking out the `using namespace std;` - it's generally considered bad form anyway :-)

I'm not sure that will fix the problem but most people either use the namespace or fully qualify things like `std::cout`. I've never seen code that does *both.*

The other thing to check is that the `iostream` header actually *is* being bought in. In other words, are there any errors on that line. A lot of problems (at least in the Windows world, so it may not necessarily apply to you) seem to be due to faulty path setup in NetBeans.

Answer (score 0):

Hey look at your Output Debug. You may see "no permission". After I changed the file permission of "/YourProjekt/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/file" to runable and everyone can read and write the error disappeared. (BTW: I had the bug because I was on a NTFS System with my Projekt, it have to be ext partition)
Hope I can help you with that.

Answer (score -1):

Try taking out the std::  next to cout